# Can we make SQL connection without using connection string. or by any alternate way

Tags: sql-server, connection

I don't wants to use connection string because on different machines data source is changing 
eg.

```
(local)
./sqlexpress
```

Comment: We had this issue. It was resolved by introducing a xml configuration and powershell commands. the powershell utility picks the server/instance name from xml file.

Comment: I don't know about power shell command and  XML configurationThen what should I do??

Comment: The fact that the machine name will change is **exactly the REASON** for using a connection string rather than hardcoding your server connection!